# JS constructor can not see the variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio Access Token on Firebase Functions with TypeScript.

```
export const returnToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const twilioAccessToken = twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
  const envconf = functions.config();
  const twilioAccountSid = envconf.twilio.sid; //saved them on environment
  console.log(twilioAccountSid); //prints out fine
  console.log(typeof twilioAccountSid !== "undefined"); //returns true
  const twilioApiKey = envconf.twilio.apikey;
  console.log(twilioApiKey); //prints fine too
  const twilioApiSecret = envconf.twilio.apisecret;
  console.log("gonna make a token"); //prints 

  const token = twilioAccessToken( //here it says TypeError: Cannot set property 'accountSid' of undefined
    twilioAccountSid,
    twilioApiKey,
    twilioApiSecret
  )
  console.log("gonna make a grant");
  const grant = new twilioAccessToken.VideoGrant();
  token.addGrant(grant);
  grant.room = "someroom";
  token.identity = "someid";
  res.send(token.toJwt());
})
```

and I get an error for the twilioAccessToken constructor which says
  `TypeError: Cannot set property 'accountSid' of undefined`

Comment: Say more details on which line, I can not see `accountSid` in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking the source ->

```
function AccessToken(accountSid, keySid, secret, options) {
  if (!accountSid) { throw new Error('accountSid is required'); }
  if (!keySid) { throw new Error('keySid is required'); }
  if (!secret) { throw new Error('secret is required'); }
  options = options || {};
  this.accountSid = accountSid;
```

AccessToken is a constructor, but your calling it like a regular function..

```
const token = twilioAccessToken(
```

You need to use `new`

```
const token = new twilioAccessToken(
```

Normal Javascript notation is if a function starts with a capital letter, it's a hint that it's a constructor.  To keep with this standard I would say you want to also rename `twilioAccessToken` to `TwilioAccessToken`..